# data type is not recognizable using Threads in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculation code using threads in Python. My code is the following:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Fact(Thread):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def factorial(self):
        p = 1
        for i in range(self.start, self.end):
            p = p * i
        return p            

    def run(self):
        global s
        s = s + self.factorial()
        sleep(2)
        print ("output is ", s)

s = 0

def main():
    n = 6
    mid = n / 2
    obj1 = Fact(1, mid)
    obj1.start()
    obj2 = Fact(mid + 1, n)
    obj2.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I want is to compute, iteratively, the factorial of a number. For example, if I enter 6 as an input it should do the following products:

```
product(1, 3) + product(4, 6)
```

The problem is that when I run this code:

```
obj1.start()
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I cannot find which one could be the mistake.

Comment: You're trying to use `start` for a method and an instance variable at the same time.

Comment: There is an instance variable in the same name (start) which is 'int' and 'int' is not callable. When you do `obj1.start`, it's actually referring to that instance variable.

Comment: `obj1.start` is not a function - did you mean `obj1.run()` instead?

Comment: BTW, while using global variables is always a bad idea, in this case it is even worse. You are using multiple threads to modify the same global variable. This can cause you pretty bad errors if one thread modifies the variable while the other one is using it.